# Upload and set image to canvas using javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How do I upload an image and set it to `canvas` background in `Internet Explorer` when I click on a button?

I tried using `FileReader()`, but it didnt work. How do I make it possible?

Comment: Internet Explorer Version?

Comment: Old one 7 That does not support HTML 5

Comment: There is no reason to support IE 7, latest IE that Microsoft supports in term of security updates is IE 11.

Comment: Yes I know but It is also not working on Edge too. I want to make sure my code works on older pc as well

Comment: @Shagun, You should not waste time in supporting obsolete browsers. Even Microsoft has junked IE

Comment: @Satpal It was an issue that i am working on github. Can u tell me how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canvas` is not supported in IE 7, but there is the script that simulate canvas: https://github.com/arv/explorercanvas

`FileReader` is not supported in IE 7 too (IE 10+ only).

Comment: i need to also upload an image file how do i do that?

Comment: Do want to preview before upload or just upload?

Comment: i think [this](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2012/04/html5-show-thumbnail-preview-of-image.html) might be helpful

Comment: It relies on `FileReader` which is not supported in IE7, only IE10+.

Comment: Yes, Thats the probleem  >:(